# How to know what version of StyleCop in used in CruiseControl.NET

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, cruisecontrol.net, visual-studio-addins, stylecop

We have Cruise Control build server that runs StyleCop and keeps failing builds. I am suspecting that version of StylecCop on server does not match version that we have on developer machines.
**How can I tell without accessing build server which version of StyleCop is it running on?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility I have noticed is when StyleCop version gets out of date, in cruise control build log following message can be found. This could be solution in some cases, but not all.

```
<target name="StyleCop" startTime="06/25/2014 10:32:52" elapsedTime="00:00:02" elapsedSeconds="2" success="true">
    <message level="normal">
        <![CDATA[StyleCop 4.7.49.0 is now available.
    StyleCop 4.7.44.0 is currently installed.

    Please consider downloading the latest version.]]>
    </message>
    <message level="normal">
        <![CDATA[No violations encountered]]>
    </message>
</target>
```